# Displaying only the last of a sequence in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that will occasionally have more than one detail record in a group.  In such a case I only want to display the last in the sequence.  I have a sequence number associated with each record so I need to suppress all detail rows in the group other than the one with the maximum sequence number.

I've tried using a global variable to recalculate the max value as of each detail record but I haven't been able to write a formula that, while printing, can use this maximum sequence number to suppress the row if it does not contain a value equal to the max sequence number.

Comment: Have you tried using arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand you have data organized by this:

```
Data1      Data2  SeQuencenumber 
1          a      1
2          b      1
2          c      2
2          d      3
```

And from what i understand your want your output look like (group by Data1):

```
Data1      Data2  SeQuencenumber 
1          a      1
2          d      3
```

To do so you need to write formula in detail section which compares your current detail sequence number and count of all for that group (Data1).  Right-click your detail section and write formula here [image]

Formula looks like :

```
if {SequenceNumber} = count ({SequenceNumber},{Data1}) then true 
else false
```

Hope it helps, if you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
Shared Stringvar array concatenate;

concatenate:=concatenate+CStr(Sequencenumber);
```

now in suppress condition of details:

```
Shared Stringvar array concatenate;
if Maximum(concatenate)=Sequencenumber
Then false
else true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried a solution similar to the one from KuKeC but with the *maximum* function instead of *count*.  But while reviewing the KuKeC solution I finally saw that I was already suppressing the detail band when a date in the detail did not match a parameter date, yet the maximum function was giving the max of all data whether displayed or not.

So I first needed to add a formula field that would return the sequence number only if the data date matched the parameter date

```
if {PSLRegister.PSLRPPStartDate} = {?PP_Start_Date} then
  {PSLRegister.PSLRSeqNo}
else
  0
```

then I used this formula field in the equation to suppress the detail record

```
Maximum({@SeqIfDateMatch}, {TrnsltEmployee.TSEmployeeID}) <> {PSLRegister.PSLRSeqNo}
```

Thanks to all